# Fuseki blocks after 5 requests

Tags: java, jena, fuseki

I have app with soap services that works with Jena TDB2 and Fuseki. It works fine but my application blocks after 5th requests to get objects from fuseki.
Here is the code

```
QueryExecution q = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(serviceURI, query);
ResultSet results = q.execSelect();
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
while (resultSet.hasNext()) {
  QuerySolution querySolution = resultSet.next();
  RDFNode object = querySolution.get("?o");
  if (object instanceof Literal) {
    model.add(querySolution.getResource("?s"), model.createProperty(querySolution.getResource("?p").toString()),
        object);
  }
  if (object instanceof Resource) {
    if (querySolution.getResource("?p").getLocalName().equals("type")) {
      model.add(querySolution.getResource("?s"), model.createProperty(querySolution.getResource("?p").toString()),
          object);
    } else {
      model.add(querySolution.getResource("?s"), model.createProperty(querySolution.getResource("?p").toString()),
          model.createProperty("#" + querySolution.getResource("?o").getLocalName()));
    }
  }
```

So what can cause this problem? I thought it is some configuration but i did not found some useful coments about this.

Comment: The code does not seem to close the QueryExecution. For external resources (network connections) it is best is to use Java try-with-resource `try(QueryExecution q = ...) { code }.` This speeds up the reusing of OS resources.

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Good - converted to an answer to make it more findable.  Could you accept it please?  Also - which version of Jena are you running? And which OS is the client code running on?

Comment: I am working on Windows OS and works fine until now, it is still not implemented and tested on Linux.

Comment: Thanks - we have seen this mostly on Linux, and in a tight loop of operations (it used to stop the test suite), so hearing about  MS Windows is useful input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code does not close the `QueryExecution`.

For external resources (network connections) it is best is to use Java "try-with-resource"

```
try(QueryExecution q = ...) { code }
```

This speeds up the reusing of OS resources.